# Cannot find the file location in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am implementing famous Iris classification problem in python for 1st time. I have a data file namely iris.data.
Sample data

Attributes are:

1.sepal length in cm 2. sepal width in cm 3. petal length in cm 4. petal width in cm 5. class:

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

I worte

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FILE_PATH = "E:/iris dataset"
MAIN_FILE_NAME = "iris.dat"
data = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(FILE_PATH,MAIN_FILE_NAME), delimiter=',')
```

Error

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py in open(self, path, mode, encoding, newline)
621                                       encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
622         else:
--> 623             raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
624
625

OSError: E:/iris dataset/iris.dat not found.

[image: File Location]

I share the screenshot of the location. I can not understand why I got this error?

Answer (score 1):

After uploading your data to gdrive try this for FILE_PATH :
`FILE_PATH = /content/drive/My Drive/<file name>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the data into google collab you cannot give local address of your computer

Comment: Local address?? How could I give it?

Comment: I am talking about the E drive that you have given into your colab, you have to upload the data on colab to get it working.